# What STOMP Header to Close a Subscription?

Tags: websocket, stomp, spring-websocket

Is there a standard way for a server to indicate to a STOMP (web socket) client that it should close the connection? (i.e. 'kick' them from a room).

From what I can tell, there is:

- a standard frame for a client to `UNSUBSCRIBE`
- no frame for kicking or force "unsubscribing" from a topic, at the server's initiative.

Use cases include: closing a topic when all other members have unsubscribed, closing a topic when its temporary use has ended (e.g. fetching a large document).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The STOMP specification has no way to tell a client it needs to unsubscribe from a destination.  In my view, if the server deems it necessary that the client should unsubscribe the server should simply disconnect the subscriber and perform the necessary server-side clean-up.  STOMP supports certain ["server" frames](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#Server_Frames) (i.e. `MESSAGE`, `RECEIPT`, & `ERROR`).  An [`ERROR`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#ERROR) frame might be suitable here.  Such a frame could include details about why the client was disconnected.

Also, it's worth noting that STOMP only specifies support for generic destinations without regard for delivery semantics so speaking about a STOMP "topic" isn't technically accurate.  Of course, implementors are free to provide the kinds of delivery semantics they want and if those semantics fit with traditional "topic" (i.e. publish/subscribe) semantics that's certainly permissible.

Comment: I will probably just message the client and 'suggest' that it unsubscribe but not enforce it, as I have control over the front end as well.

Thanks for your answer and for the clarifications!